# $this->registerPolicies method in AppServiceProvider not found for Passport in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport

I am developing an REST api using Laravel. What I am trying to do now is installing the Passport. I am using Laravel 5.4 version because I am maintaining a legacy system. I integrated the Passport following this official docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport. But I am getting an error.

First I installed the Passport running this composer command

```
composer require laravel/passport:~4.0
```

Then I added this provider class to the config/app.php file

```
Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
```

Then I run these commands

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan passport:install
```

Which was fine because it gave me the expected output.

Then I modified the app\User class. This is the User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Then I modified the guards section of config/auth.php as follow.

```
 'guards' => [
      'web' => [
         //'driver' => 'session',
         'driver' => 'aws-cognito',
         'provider' => 'users',
      ],

      'api' => [
         'driver' => 'passport', //'token',
         'provider' => 'users',
      ],
   ],
```

Then I modified the AppServiceProvider. This is my AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Validator;
use Schema;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();

    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/../Helpers/CommonHelper.php';
    }
}
```

This line is giving me the error

```
$this->registerPolicies();
```

Saying method not found. If I commented out that line the application was running. But I should not comment out that line because now I want to protect my API.

For example, I have an API route in the routes/api.php

```
Route::get('event/list', 'Api\EventController@getEventList');
```

But I want to protect it with the Passport. Now, I can access that API endpoint directly from the browser What is missing in my code to authenticate the API route with Passport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend your `AppServiceProvider` from `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider
```

or better create new service provider, which extends `AuthServiceProvider`, because `AppServiceProvider` is very overall provider.

Comment: Or you can use "use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;" https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#writing-gates

Answer (score 0):

You can re-define registerPolicies function in your service provider.

```
protected function registerPolicies() {
    foreach ($this->policies as $model => $policy) {
        Gate::policy($model, $policy);
    }
}
```